# do while loop didn't execute in desired way

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to make a do...while loop to prevent the user from entering a value other than an integer for the temperature in degrees Fahrenheit. If the user inputs a non-integer value, the loop will go back to the message "What is the temperature (in Fahrenheit degree): " and let the user attempt to enter a correct input again. However, when I execute the following code, it only lets me enter the value beside the error message "Invalid input" to transfer the input value into the Celsius degree.

```
using System;

namespace SimpleTempConversion
{
    public class FahrenheitToCelsiusV2
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Declare a variable of type 'double' to hold the temperature obtained from the user

            double f;

            // Declare a variable of type 'double' to hold the converted temperature
            double c;

            // Declare a bool to record if the user has entered in a valid number yet
            string fahren;
            do
            {// Display "What is the temperature (in degrees Fahrenheit): "
                Console.Write("What is the temperature (in degrees Fahrenheit): ");

                // Use TryParse() to read the Fahrenheit temperature. Set the bool variable
                // declared earlier to the result of TryParse()
                fahren = Console.ReadLine();
                f = double.TryParse(fahren);
                double.TryParse(fahren, out f);

                // Check the bool variable to see if TryParse() failed to parse
                if (f == false)
                {
                    // Display "Invalid input" on a line by itself.
                    Console.Write("Invalid input");
                }

                // The code should loop while the input is not valid
            } while (f == false);

            // Convert the Fahrenheit temperature into degrees Celsius
            c = (5.0 / 9.0) * (f - 32);

            // Display "The temperature is (temperature here) degrees Celsius"
            Console.WriteLine("The temperature is " + c + " degrees Celsius");

            // Prompt the user to press enter to close the window
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
What is the temperature (in degrees Fahrenheit): 

ssd

Invalid input

What is the temperature (in degrees Fahrenheit): 

12

What is the temperature (in degrees Fahrenheit): 

Invalid input12

The temperature is -11.1111111111111 degrees Celsius
Press enter to exit.
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jijvq.png)

Comment: Set f to true if the entry is right

Comment: That's not your actual code... and you're confusing the return value of `TryParse` with the output parameter.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! I have fixed the problem with Console.Write(). It seems like if the input value does not sit on the same line of  "What is the temperature" message, it will not be reading by Console.ReadLine() and outputting the desired result. Thanks to all of you again and have a nice day!!!

Answer (score 1):

I made your code a little bit shorter, you can use `!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out f)` as a while loop condition and get rid of unnecessary variables and if clauses:

```
public static void Main()
{
    double f;

    double c;

    Console.Write("What is the temperature (in degrees Fahrenheit): ");

    while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out f))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
        Console.Write("What is the temperature (in degrees Fahrenheit): ");
    }

    c = (5.0 / 9.0) * (f - 32);

    Console.WriteLine("The temperature is " + c + " degrees Celsius");

    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You can test my code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IIY6bH

Output on my machine:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Slaven but when I try to execute your code on my Mac, it has the same output as I did before. I am wondering if there is a way to fix that. *When I try to enter the integer, it gets me to another "what is the temperature" message. But when I try to type the integer next to the "invalid input" message it transfer to the Celsius temperature.*

Comment: I run the code and had no problems. I added a link to the answer where you can test my code. What IDE are you using, maybe you need to rebuild your solution after you copy my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using variable `f` for too many things. What you should have is 2 separate variables, one for the value and one for whether the parse was successful.

```
bool parseOk = false;
do
{
    ...
    parseOk = double.TryParse(fahren, out f);
    ...
}
while(!parseOk)
```